# disabling focus for a second form when interacted with, keeping focus on main form

Tags: c#

This is my first question here. I've started learning to code in C# last week and came across the following issue I couldn't find an answer for (my previous programming experience is with microcontrollers in C so I'm still getting used to the object-oriented approach).

I have a form which calls up a second form (which will be like an onscreen keyboard). I want that the second form to not take focus when it's buttons are clicked so that if a textbox in the 1st form is selected, the keys will be sent to it.

using `p.ExStyle |= 0x8000000;` in the second form works for any other window (like notepad) but not for first form, it looses focus when the 2nd form is interacted with. Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

Form1:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frm2.Show();
        }

    }
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        protected override CreateParams CreateParams // do not activate window when interacted with
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams p = base.CreateParams;
                p.ExStyle |= 0x8000000;
                return p;
            }
        }
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("test");
        }
    }
```

[image: Screenshot of the forms]

Comment: umm not really sure about your requirement, but are you trying to keep focus on `Form2` only, while it is open, if that is the case then use `frm2.ShowDialog();` instead of just `Show();`.

Comment: Use an event generated by the second form to send the data to your first form. SendKeys is the wrong function to be using.

Comment: Using the WM_EX_NOACTIVATE style flag only prevents your *application* from getting activated.  It doesn't stop activation of the window if your app is already in the foreground.  That requires a bigger weapon, override WndProc() and return MA_NOACTIVATE when you get the WM_MOUSEACTIVATE message.  And you can't use button controls anymore, you have to paint them instead.  Have you considered using the built-in osk.exe?

Comment: Habib, no actually I'm trying to keep focus on the first form. Mark, I considered that but haven't looked enough to learn how to do it properly. Hans, that sounds like a lot for my level. I can compile this as a separate program and use it as an on screen keyboard, but I wanted to integrate it to the main program so that I could show it when an editable text field is selected. I could open and close it as a program each time but I don't think it's really good practice. Ill try to implement what Mark said even though I don't know yet how to exactly. The main form will have multiple text fields